# Pushing Stripe Token to Cloud Function Firebase (iOS Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've been trying to push my stripe token to the cloud function for Firebase. I haven't made any changes to the cloud function that is provided in their tutorial in terms of how it accepts the token.

But I am having trouble pushing the token to `/stripe_customers/(uid)/sources` using iOS (Swift). In the node.js example provided by Firebase, they use a push() method that takes in the token as a parameter and creates a payment source. I read that childByAutoId behaves the same way in iOS (Swift) but I do not know how to make it go through because the method doesn't take in any parameters.

Here's what I have right now:

```
func chargeUsingToken(token: STPToken) {
    ref?.child("/stripe_customers/(uid!)/sources").childByAutoId().setValue(token)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cloud function from your tutorial should provided a `path or route` on how to interact with it. For example if you had a regular `node.js express app or api` running from `ip:#PORT`, if you were to talk to it you'd do `ip:PORT/welcome`(where /welcome is just one path in your api)

> Now keep in mind that your cloud function can be invoked via HTTP

So from your iOS app, you need to add that token into a `Dictionary` (but you need to know which key to associate your token value it **[somekey:tokenValue]**), then you'd post into your cloud function **(using either Alamofire or URLSession)** at that specify path.

This not the exact answer, however I figure out that is your first time using `cloud function` and I just wanted to give you some kind of heads up :)